using clang to generate .o files for .i files generated by gcc, errors occur
The code example is very simple.
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        printf("hello, world");
}


Generate the .i file.


gcc -E test.cpp -o test.cpp.ii


generate .o files for .i files


clang++ -c test.cpp.ii  -o test.cpp.o

The following error message is displayed.
In file included from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/stdio.h:189:48: error: '__malloc__' attribute takes no arguments
  __attribute__ ((__malloc__)) __attribute__ ((__malloc__ (fclose, 1))) ;
                                               ^
/usr/include/stdio.h:201:49: error: '__malloc__' attribute takes no arguments
   __attribute__ ((__malloc__)) __attribute__ ((__malloc__ (fclose, 1))) ;
                                                ^
/usr/include/stdio.h:223:77: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_free'; did you mean '__builtin_frexp'?
   noexcept (true) __attribute__ ((__malloc__)) __attribute__ ((__malloc__ (__builtin_free, 1)));
                                                                            ^
/usr/include/stdio.h:223:77: note: '__builtin_frexp' declared here
/usr/include/stdio.h:223:65: error: '__malloc__' attribute takes no arguments
   noexcept (true) __attribute__ ((__malloc__)) __attribute__ ((__malloc__ (__builtin_free, 1)));

btw, When using gcc to generate .o files from .i files, everything works fine.

attribute ((malloc)) is a feature unique to GCC support?
In this case, how to make clang generate .o files correctly


After a lot of investigation I found this in glibc's stddef.h:
/* At some point during the gcc 2.96 development the `malloc' attribute
   for functions was introduced.  We don't want to use it unconditionally
   (although this would be possible) since it generates warnings.  */
#if __GNUC_PREREQ (2,96) || __glibc_has_attribute (__malloc__)
# define __attribute_malloc__ __attribute__ ((__malloc__))
#else
# define __attribute_malloc__ /* Ignore */
#endif

and if you see stdio.h, for example:
#undef __attr_dealloc_fclose
#define __attr_dealloc_fclose __attr_dealloc (fclose, 1)

...
...
...

extern FILE *fopen (const char *__restrict __filename,
            const char *__restrict __modes)
  __attribute_malloc__ __attr_dealloc_fclose __wur;

So, those attributes in your case, are from glibc, not gcc, and I think it is better to not play with them. So I tested it with musl libc in my arch linux:
pacman -Sy musl

then
gcc -ansi -pedantic -nostdinc -I /usr/lib/musl/include/ -E test.cpp -o test.cpp.ii
clang++ -c test.cpp.ii -o test.cpp.o

at least it worked for me. I hope it will be useful for you.
You can fill a bug to glibc to not define those attributes at least for -pedantic.

Perhaps I didn't describe the scenario clearly. That test.cpp is simply provided as an example for reproducing the issue. In fact, I don't have the source code or a compilation environment. All I have is a .i file. My expectation is to take this .i file, compile it into a .o file through LLVM obfuscation, and then give the .o file back.

then I think you must edit those .i files manually and remove all those attributes using sed or editors bulk replace. you'll lose a bit of optimization i think.

since all of those attributes in glibc implemented using macros, you can manually use alternate version (expand to blank) of macros. i can't recommend this generally.

Thank you for your answer sincerely.  "So, those attributes in your case, are from glibc, not gcc".  For this statement, header files(stdio.h, stddef.h, etc.) are part of GCC, right?

No, they are part of glibc.
